# why do i get an error connection in nodejs - mysql (trying remote connection)

Tags: mysql, node.js, dbconnection

I recently started learning Nodejs to connect to MySQL and i'm having connection issues. I tried using putty to connect and i'm able to do so without any issues

this is my **example.route.js** file

```
const express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: <ipaddress>,
    port: <default Port>,
    user: 'root',
    password: <given password>,
    database: <db name>,
    connectionTimeout: 30000
});

connection.connect((error) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log('error connecting: ' + error);
    } else {
        console.log('Connected to server');
    }
});

connection.query('SELECT * FROM test', function(err, results, fields) {

    console.log('results in table: ' + results);
    console.log('fields in table: ' + fields); // -1

    connection.release();

    if (err) throw error;
});
connection.end();

module.exports = router;
```

i get the following error => `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED` **(Will update with complete error in a few hours)**

As i mentioned before i used **PUTTY** in order to make sure there was an issue when connecting but i was able to connect to the given database name, host with the same user and password.

Not sure if this helps is an *ubuntu server with MySQL*

Anyone has an idea of why i'm getting the connection error? I would appreciate it the help

Comment: `root@localhost` != `root@%` (Different source IP's may result in a different password or no access all together). Ensure that you're connecting in the same manner that you are connecting via Putty. (Same source IP address, same password, same port). Verify 3306 is open/accessible.

Comment: @FrankerZ I used the same ipadress, same user, same password and same port 3306 to connect in both putty and mysql createConnection. i am sure 3306 is open/accessible but will take a look and get back with more info

Comment: Try both `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` (There are differences between the 2)

Comment: @FrankerZ i tried all and still giving me the same error. not sure if this helps but the server is not run locally. i am trying to connect remotely to it so we have been looking into anything else that might causing this issue. we also opened the 3306 access from outside and still the same error

Comment: yeah, i'll connect later today and thanks for the help

Comment: solved the issue, i had to use an ssh tunnel in order to connect to the remote server and then database

Comment: You're not going to be doing that in production are you?

Comment: more than likely not